# How to save Unicode text using stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, unicode

I am working on an multilingual web application being developed in VS 2010 - ASP.Net (C#).

I can insert it without any problem if I use a simple insert statement without stored procedure for example

```
Insert INTO Test (E,A) VALUES('Some English Text',N'الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِاللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِاللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِاللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِاللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ')
```

It works fine when I add N for unicode data. My question is how can I add this 'N' in stored procedure so that it can save data without any issues. I tried to put N in different way but stored procedure give syntax error

Below is the example of stored procedure I am using.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AddNewPageDetails]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @PageNameEnglish varchar(100),
            @PageNameArabic nvarchar(300),
            @PageTitleEnglish varchar(300),
            @PageTitleArabic nvarchar(900),
            @PageDescEnglish varchar(400),
            @PageDescArabic nvarchar(1200),
            @PageKeywordsEnglish varchar(120),
            @PageKeywordsArabic nvarchar(400),
            @PageBodyEnglish varchar(MAX),
            @PageBodyArabic nvarchar(MAX),
            @PageLinkPosition int,    
AS
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO pg_Pages(
    PageNameEnglish,PageNameArabic,PageTitleEnglish,PageTitleArabic,PageDescEnglish,
    PageDescArabic,PageKeywordsEnglish,PageKeywordsArabic,PageBodyEnglish,
    PageLinkPosition,PageLayoutPosition,PageBannerImageEnglish,)
    VALUES
    (@PageNameEnglish,@PageNameArabic,@PageTitleEnglish,@PageTitleArabic,@PageDescEnglish,
    @PageDescArabic,@PageKeywordsEnglish,@PageKeywordsArabic,@PageBodyEnglish,)
END
```

Reply is appreciated.

Comment: The stored proc seems fine - can you **show us** how you **call** this stored proc from your C# code?? Also, as a side note: it's store*D* procedure (with a **D** at the end) - **STORED** in SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks noticing those typos. Stored procedure works fine now i deleted & recreated the stored procedure & now it is working like charm... One part of question is solved other part is do we need to put N in SP as we have to put it in simple SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE statement to get the right.

Comment: I reword his question: To show a string literal is unicode, we put N before it: `N'الحمدلله رب العالمین'` Now what syntax we have to show a @variable is unicode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The N is part of a Unicode string literal, just as the quotes. Probably you tried to add an N with the @parameter name, but this is not necessary (even wrong).

So calling your SP in T-SQL using syntax like

```
EXEC usp_AddNewPageDetails 'english text', N'arab text', etc.
```

is sufficient.

If you call the SP from .Net via SqlCommand etc., no additional code is required, as .Net always uses Unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the data types of the columns in table pg_Pages are NVARCHAR where appropriate?  If the columns are VARCHAR then unicode text will be converted to junk without warning.